# How to set a label to a resource with jena

Tags: jena

In my ontology I'm using [SKOS](http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/) concepts. In the documentation there are labels (like `prefLabel`, etc., `mentioned`): `http://www.w3.org/TR/skos-reference/#labels`.
How can I set such a label to a resource in Jena with defining the language?
My example to add a concept looks like this:

```java
 Resource skosConcept = infModel.createResource("http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept");
 Resource instance =  infModel.createResource("http://eg.com#Instance");
 infModel.add(instance, RDF.type, skosConcept);
```

But how can I define, for example, the `skos:prefLabel`? With a property to my instance resource? And how to set the language?  The class [OntResource](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntResource.html) seems to have such a property for adding a label with language . But I'm using an [InfModel](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/InfModel.html) so I can't get the resource as an `OntResource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you created the resource with createResource, you can create properties with [createProperty](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/ModelCon.html#createProperty(java.lang.String)), and then add the desired triple to the model in the same way that you already used.  The literal with a language type can be created with [createLiteral](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/rdf/model/Model.html#createLiteral%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.InfModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.Reasoner;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.ReasonerRegistry;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDF;

public class SKOS {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();
        InfModel infModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, model);

        String skos = "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#";

        Resource skosConcept = infModel.createResource( skos+"Concept" );
        Resource instance =  infModel.createResource("http://eg.com#Instance");

        infModel.add(instance, RDF.type, skosConcept);

        Property prefLabel = infModel.createProperty( skos+"prefLabel" );
        Literal label = infModel.createLiteral( "a preferred label in English", "en" );

        // either of these lines is fine
        instance.addLiteral( prefLabel, label );
        infModel.add( instance, prefLabel, label );

        model.write( System.out, "N3" );
    }
}
```

This code also shows the model, just so that we can see that the property is getting set as

```
<http://eg.com#Instance>
  a       <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept> ;
  <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel>
          "a preferred label in English"@en .
```